# How to map html files in spring security without Thymeleaf and web.xml

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot

I am trying to implement Spring Security and map the home page which is an HTML page from the Spring Security.
It works with the Thymeleaf dependency in `pom.xml`, but not without it. I do not want to use it. Moreover I need to use Angularjs partials in the mapping.
My IDE is IntelliJ.

How do I do this without Thymeleaf?

Answer (score 0):

Create a subclass of

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter

@Configuration
public class ResourceConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
```

in

```
WebMvcConfigurerAdapter.addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry)
```

add your resource mappings :

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/index.html").addResourceLocations(resourcePath);
```

resourcePath  is the path to your resource e.g.
html/index.html if its in src/main/reources/html

you can also make generic mappings.